# Why doesn't my DataGridView display any data?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I've been using listviews successfully in a fairly complex app, but I really want to use a DataGridView, and I haven't been able to get it to work.  I'm using classes or my own pseudo-middleware to read the data, and have avoided binding tables to controls.  Here's a simplified example of code that doesn't work right.

```
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim nrows as Integer

    ds = dbio.ReadLocations("") 'Reads place names, with an optional search string
    nrows = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count

    'Note: I can insert code here that successfully displays the data in a listview

    Dim dtStates As DataTable = New DataTable("TableName")
    Dim drStates As DataRow 'A component row of dtstates
    Dim dr As DataRow 'A component row of the result set, ds
    dtStates.Clear()

    'There are just 3 columns in the data grid
    dtStates.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(String))
    dtStates.Columns.Add("StateName", GetType(String))
    dtStates.Columns.Add("Country", GetType(String))

    'Build the data table, row-by-row
    For i = 1 To nRows
        dr = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i - 1)  'Get a row from the populated data set

        drStates = dtStates.NewRow     'Create a new row object
        'Populate the new row object
        drStates("ID") = dr("ID").ToString    
        drStates("StateName") = dr("StateName")
        drStates("Country") = dr("Country")
        'Put the new row object into the data table
        dtStates.Rows.Add(drStates)
    Next

    'Bind the DataGridView to my data table
    grdStates.DataSource = dtStates
```

My grid "lights up" as it were, and clearly has the appropriate number of rows, just no data.  My best guess is that I need to define a DataMember for my DataGridView, but I can't imagine what value should be placed there. I've tried grdStates.DataMember="TableName" and other values (even ""), but nothing works.

Comment: Are you sure that nRows > 0 ?

Comment: Absolutely.  It's 68.  And there are 68 empty rows in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I will make an assumption here, since I can't yet add a comment to your question, and that is that you created your DataGridView and added columns to it independently of the columns added to dtStates.
I recently experienced the same problem you have, which led me to your question.
My problem was that I had defined a DataGridView with 3 columns, then set its datasource to a dataTable which already had 3 columns. I thought it would map the datatable's columns to the DataGridView. In fact it only displayed the three columns I had added via the design interface for each row in the datatable, but they were empty.

My first clue to this was when I selected a row and hit Ctrl+C, then pasted the results in Notepad++. I saw 4 tab stops before the "first" column.
I deleted the manual column definitions from the DataGridView so that its only columns come from the datatable I assigned to it. Now the data shows as expected.

I still need to figure out how to format the columns to the width I want, but at least the data is there now. Hope that helps! Surf Wisely.